# How do I stop this constant loss of free space?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

I was running Ubuntu, as normal, when suddenly I got a dialog box that said I only had 1.2 GB of free space left. An hour before, I had 30 GB of free space.

I deleted some stuff and brought the free space up to 25 GB. But it continues to decrease. I tried removing old log files and truncating log files and such, and it continues to decrease!

I tried using Disk Analyzer to find where all this free space loss was coming from and that didn't work, as it showed everything as it should be. I rebooted and eventually Ubuntu did a disk check that somehow brought the free space back up to 40 GB but it still continues to decrease about 10 GB a day. I continue to try and find new ways to free space, but its like an automated process of decreasing disk space that I cannot get to stop.

I don't know what to do. How can I find the cause, and stop my free space from decreasing?

Here is the output from `sudo du -sh /var/* ~/.xsession-errors`:

```
13M /var/backups
204M    /var/cache
112M    /var/crash
4.0K    /var/games
503M    /var/lib
4.0K    /var/local
0       /var/lock
9.5G    /var/log
85M     /var/mail
4.0K    /var/metrics
24K     /var/opt
0       /var/run
1.7M    /var/spool
391M    /var/tmp
11G     /var/tvmobili
20K     /var/www
224K    /home/school/.xsession-errors
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to append the output of `sudo du -sh /var/* ~/.xsession-errors` please? (those two places I would expect to blow up if there is something being silly). Otherwise, I'm with Eliah - this is indicative of disk issues. Take this seriously.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You've got some out-of-control logs. Instead of deleting like crazy everyday, find the fast growing file or files, and *look* inside to investigate what may be causing this. Maybe some program is spinning in a loop logging some condition. Either disable that program, disable its logging or try to fix the condition that it's complaining about.

If a file is growing before your eyes, and you have no idea which program is writing to it, you may be able to find that out easily.  Here is an example. Who has `/var/log/syslog` open? We use the `fuser` command:

```
# fuser /var/log/syslog
/var/log/syslog:      602
```

Only one process has `/var/log/syslog` open. It is process 602. What is that? Let us not bother with `ps` and `grep`, but look at the `/proc` filesystem directly:

```
# ls -l /proc/602/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 29 17:45 /proc/602/exe -> /usr/sbin/rsyslogd
```

Aha, it is `rsyslogd`. We are not surprised that `rsyslogd` has `/var/log/syslog/` open.

This method is not guaranteed to work. The reason is that programs do not have to keep files open ino rder to write to them. Suppose you have a process which opens a file, appends to it, and then closes it. You will have a somewhat more difficult investigation. You could run `fuser` many times until by chance you catch the process "red handed". That process itself could be going into and out of existence quickly. Another problem is that multiple processes could have the file open, but only one is making it larger. In that case, you can trace their system calls.

```
# fuser /var/log/huge-annoying-file
/var/log/huge-annoying-file:   1234 23459
```

Oops! Two processes have it open: 1234 and 23459. Let's see what they are doing:

```
# strace -p 1234
Process 1234 attached - interrupt to quit
select(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, {9, 922666}
```

It's not doing anything, just blocking in a `select` call. Ctrl-C to break the trace:

```
select(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, {9, 922666}^C <unfinished ...>
```

Check the next one:

```
# strace -p 23459
write(5, "Useless garbage ..."..., 512) = 512
write(5, "More useless garbage ..."..., 512) = 512
write(5, "More useless garbage ..."..., 512) = 512
write(5, "More useless garbage ..."..., 512) = 512
write(5, "More useless garbage ..."..., 512) = 512
write(5, "More useless garbage ..."..., 512) = 512
write(5, "More useless garbage ..."..., 512) = 512
^C
```

Oops, that one is writing constantly. It must be the bad one. We can even check that the file descriptor 5 which the process is writing to is in fact the large file:

```
# ls -l /proc/23459/fd/5
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Apr  3 23:39 /proc/23459/fd/5 -> /var/log/huge-annoying-file
```

I don't suspect you have a corrupt filesystem, but to force a full check, you don't have to boot a DVD.

Firstly, review your filesystem's maximum mount count setting. Identify your partition using the df command. Example on an Ubuntu system I have here:

```
# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       18062108 5499320  11645284  33% /
udev              392152       4    392148   1% /dev
tmpfs             159768     768    159000   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              399416     200    399216   1% /run/shm
/dev/sr0           43668   43668         0 100% /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.1.4_74291
```

You can see that the `/` filesystem is mounted on `/dev/sda1`. So `/dev/sda1` is the storage device of the root partition (and the only partition in this particular system).

Let's look at some attributes of that filesystem. This is safe to do even though it is mounted. The command spews a lot of output. Here is an excerpt:

```
$ dumpe2fs /dev/sda1
dumpe2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
[ ... SNIP ... ]
Last mount time:          Fri Mar 29 17:45:18 2013
Last write time:          Tue Mar  5 09:08:03 2013
Mount count:              22
Maximum mount count:      22
[ ... SNIP ... ]
```

Hey look, the mount count is equal to the maximum mount count. Next time I reboot, there will be a filesystem check.  The important thing is that the mount count is a positive value. If yours is zero, change it to some positive value like 22 using `tune2fs -c 22 /dev/whatever`. Zero means that a check is never forced regardless of how many times the partition is mounted.  Rarely rebooted systems should have low values here. A server that goes down once a year could probably use a fsck each time it reboots. You can set date-based check intervals also.

Now to force a check, you can override the *actual* count to be greater than or equal to the maximum, and then reboot. That's done with capital `C`: `tune2fs -C 1234 /dev/whatever`. Now the partition looks like it has been mounted 1234 times without a check, which is greater than the one- or two-digit maximum.

Comment: very informative but the problem is solved, it was the firewall writing huge log files

Comment: See, as I suspected. No mysterious disk corruption flogging the space up and down. I mean that could explain an isolated incident, but once it's repaired, it should be repaired. And the drive is failing, you would expect some errors in the kernel log and panics.

Comment: yeah i figured it wasnt the drive, SMART tests say its an old drive but still operable and working

Comment: An easier way to fsck all your filesystems is to run 'sudo touch /forcefsck; sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now'.

Answer (score 3):

A disk check freed some of the space, suggesting that this problem (or part of it) may be due to filesystem corruption. If that is the case, then you should be able to free more space by scanning and repairing the filesystem. However, if the corruption is perpetually happening (which might or might not be the case), that usually means the hard drive is dying. **If your backups (of your documents and any other important files that would be hard to replace) aren't completely up to date, please back up everything important now!**

To check *and repair* the disk, it cannot be mounted (at least not read-write). So you should run the repair utility from a live environment (live CD/DVD or USB). First, you'll have to find out the device name of the partition that contains your files.

Therefore, *in the installed system*, run:

```
mount | grep ' on / '
```

(Make sure to include the space between the `/` and `'`.)

You'll get something like:

```
/dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

The text before `on`--in the example from my machine, `/dev/sda8`--is the full device name for your root partition (`/`). Write this down--you'll need it.

Then boot your computer from an Ubuntu desktop CD/DVD or USB flash drive, like what you used to install Ubuntu originally. **(If this is a Wubi system, installed with the Windows installer, please let us know. I don't expect that, given what you've reported, but if that is the case, the procedure will be different.)**

Select *Try Ubuntu without installing* (not *Install Ubuntu*). When you get a functioning desktop, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a Terminal window. Then run this command:

```
sudo e2fsck -fkccp /dev/sda8
```

But make sure to replace **`/dev/sda8`** with the right full device name for your `/` partition, as you obtained through the method detailed above.

This may take a while. The `c` options included in that command cause it to scan the surface of the disk for errors as well as the filesystem (and to mark any bad areas as bad so they are not used). You can leave `cc` out if you like (if you do, you can also leave out `k`), but I recommend keeping them in.

You may be prompted about fixing certain problems, if `e2fsck` thinks there's a significant likelihood that trying to fix them could cause data loss. (The `p` makes it so that it will fix any problems that it is confident it can fix without causing complications.)

I recommend that you be strongly inclined to allow it to fix whatever it wants, **since you should only be doing this *after* making sure your backups are current**, anyway. If you want it to attempt even potentially dangerous fixes without prompting you, replace the `p` with `y`.

After this, boot back into your Ubuntu system and see if space is freed. *If it is not, or if the problem continues, please comment and edit your question to provide details.*

Comment: what if i have nothing to backup to?

Comment: @user2045360 Steal, pillage, borrow or buy some. Or push it online (Ubuntu One, Dropbox, Google Docs, S3, etc).

Comment: @user2045360 It depends how many and what kind of important files you have. If they consist of 20 office documents (or even 100, if you're patient), you can email them to yourself. You can also use cloud storage services, like Ubuntu One or DropBox (just be careful--if you set something up to sync, and a file is deleted or changed on your computer, the same change will happen in the cloud). On the other hand, if you're a filmmaker and you have 300 gigabytes of footage, then your only option is probably to buy (or, as Oli suggests, borrow) some storage media, like an external hard drive.

Comment: i have no money and noone to borrow from, how much of a possibility is data loss with this command?

Comment: @user2045360 The likelihood of data loss from that `e2fsck` commandd is pretty low, especially if you don't press `y` for anything that warns you that you may lose data. But *running that command is not why you need to back up your data.* You need to back up your data because the rapid and continual nature of your drop in free space strongly suggests that your hard drive may be about to *totally fail physically*. If that happens, you'll lose any data on it, and almost certainly not be able to recover any of it. Other ways to back up include over a network to another machine, or to CD/DVD.

Comment: i just ran a SMART hard drive test and there r no signs the hard drive will fail soon

Comment: @user2045360 That's somewhat encouraging, though SMART will not *always* be able to tell. Can you add [the information Oli requested](http://askubuntu.com/questions/277664/how-do-i-stop-this-constant-loss-of-free-space/277670?noredirect=1#comment348414_277664) to your question?

Comment: ok i added the output of that to the question

Comment: wait.....is 11 G 11 gigabytes?! why in the world is tvmobili putting ou so many errors, i have it configured properly

Comment: @user2045360 `/var` is not just for logs (`/var/log` is). Maybe `/var/tvmobili` contains video data? (Your 9.5 GB `/var/log` is big, too; mine us 19M!) Disk Usage Analyzer should've showed all this to you, so I assumed the problem wasn't files accumulating in `/var`. But it seems I assumed too quickly... By the way, unless the freeing of space after the automatic disk check was *coincidence* (which *is* possible), you still may have problems with your disk (or at least the filesystem). Does *rebooting* increase the amount of free space available?

Comment: no, and u may be right, now that i think of it, i did truncate the xsession errors log before the reboot that had the disk check, but how do i get rid of all of that data, and /var/log had 9.5 GB i want it gone, i dont really need those logs do i? how do i get rid of it

Comment: by the way heres the results of the SMART test http://screencloud.net/v/x1Gp

Comment: those 42 bad sectors have been there for over 4 years, before i even got the laptop, so i dont think they r causing a problem

Comment: how do i get rid of those 9.5 GB of logs?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8188/discussion-between-user2045360-and-eliah-kagan)

Answer (score 0):

this problem has been solved, it was the firewall writing tons of logs and tvmobili encoding files